# What is the best way to implement spi using 8085?

Tags: spi, processor, 8085

I have to make a compass using 8085. I have to take serial data from magnetometer of mpu9250. Should i prefer bit banging to implement spi or make parallel out and parallel in hardware using shift registers, since 8085 can easily process parallel data.  I want to implement the least complex method.

Comment: The word _"easiest"_ is quite subjective... Also, when you're asking how to implement algorithms, you should talk about what you're doing and what your endgame is.

Comment: I have edited the question to give more information about the project and made it more objective.

Comment: Pretty much everything on the 8080A (NMOS) and 8085 cores is memory mapped in some way: either I/O or plain memory, depending on instructions used. If you use I/O instructions and there will be more than one external device you'll need decoding. Otherwise, I think you can just use the \$IO/\overline{M}\$ line and ignore decoding if just one device, using also IOR and IOW. You can talk either to the 82C55 or even a PIC16F57 (which equals a cheap, big set of I/O pins), I suppose. The rest is software.

Comment: Searching for "the best way" is rarely warranted in engineering, rather, you should be looking for a feasible way satisfying your design constraints. If you know how to bit-bang SPI and consider it'll be fast enough, go with that.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with bit banging the I/O pins on the 8255 or 82C55. I have done that with PIC MPU's. They should NOT be the same pins that normally perform RD/WR/CS/ALE or other handshake functions.

SPI only needs a few pins to operate, but do not expect 50 MHZ performance for a microSD card. Not from the 8255. You may have to insert a few nops to insure data is stable before you read or write, but as slow as the 8255 is you may not need to.

The 8255 would give you 24 I/O pins with little drive current, but enough to drive the 74HC299 PIPO shift register. Be sure to shift in or out 8 bits at a time. During each bit shift you need to clock the microSD or whatever memory you choose.

Consider using flash memory with a 8/16 bit parallel port, then the shift register is not needed. Normally a CPU has *no* pins to bit-bang, as RD/WR/CS and ALE are driven by internal sequencers.

I know of no minimum speed issues with SPI itself, but your target IC may have timing issues so be sure it has a 'static' mode where the clock can be frozen.

Look at this link:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_8255

You can see that only port C can be bit-banged on a per bit basis. Ports A and B should be your data ports. You *could* use a 16 bit parallel port flash memory if you can find one.

Comment: With narrow exception the 8085 doesn't have "I/O pins" as it is a microprocessor rather than a microcontroller.

Comment: I will use commonly utilized 8255 for input output with 8085. I know input output with external input output ports is more complex , what im not sure is if bit banging in 8085 is doable as i could not find any examples , assuming spi protocol is dc static and there is no speed issue.

Comment: @ChrisStratton. Thanks for the heads up. My bad. Must get more sleep...

Comment: I have to give serial output, so how can flash memory replace shift register with parallel in and shift out ?

Comment: I did not know you were so short on spare pins for the 8255. If you have 4 spare pins you can work with SPI flash memory. Forget the shift registers and emulate them in code.